# Can I create a trigger depending on action on other tables?

Tags: sql, mariadb, database-trigger

Can I create a trigger on a table depending on actions on other tables D and E?

Basically, I want to create a trigger on table A that AS SOON AS a hotel opens his calendar (table C), this table gets all the basic informations from other tables (B, C and E):

- Table B: Rooms total (a calculation based on other tables) /rooms
  left(so rooms total)/rooms_booked (so 0) + identification of this
  hotel
- Table C: The date of calendar concerned
- Table D: A booking of rooms
- Tabld E: A withdraw of rooms

For the update, I would like an equivalent with AS SOON AS a room of this hotel is booked (D) or withdrawn (E) because this table is not available due to construction, water damages, or any hazard.

Also, I read that there was a limit on the numbers of triggers I can create on a table.
Is there a limit to SET on each triggers?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the mariaDB tag. Thanks America :) Great song!

Comment: Triggers run actions based on the current table, not other tables. So you can have a before/after insert, a before/after update, and a before/after delete for a table, which is at least 6 triggers per table (one for each before/after action type). Triggers have **NO** knowledge of other table action(s) when triggered. For trigger limits, see [this info](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/trigger-limitations/), and the 3rd bullet relative to the version which can have additional triggers. Not clear on what D or E do, but triggers cannot perform actions on the same table itself. (no recursive actions)